# Unity Mobile Notifications - Setting Vibration pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, push-notification, android-notifications

I'm trying to set up the unity mobile notification system but when i set VibrationPattern prop of Channel settings I'm getting this error and notification channel is not created correctly. Also if I delete the VibrationPattern line, it works OK.
Can someone realize what's going on here ? Thanks!

```
 public void CreateChannel()
{
    var c = new AndroidNotificationChannel()
    {
        Id = "default_id",
        Name = "Default Channel",
        Importance = Importance.High,
        Description = "Default Notifications",
        EnableVibration = true,
        LockScreenVisibility = LockScreenVisibility.Public,
        EnableLights = true,
        VibrationPattern = new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000}
    };
    AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(c);
}
```

And I'm getting this error on the app:

[image: Error]

Comment: what is your android version?

Comment: Hi,Huawei Mate 20 Lite, android EMUI 9.1.0